# Model-View-Controller - Which component traditionally handles file I/O?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, file-io

In a traditional MVC application, which component (model, view, or controller) is responsible for reading/writing the model to/from disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** model layer.

Most of the forms of storage are part of model layer *(with exception of templates and autoloader for class)*. In a fully realized mode layer you would have a group of objects which are directly interacting with low level storage (SQL, cache, REST API, noSQL, file system, etc. ) abstractions.

If you application is actively reading and writing to the filesystem (it could be actually mounted remote MemoryFS, which you mounted via Fuse through SSH tunnel .. it does not matter), this would be handled by structures, which deal with storage logic. Usually some form of [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) (thought it also might be [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html), [units of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html), [DAOs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) and/or some similar structures).

The storage abstraction are usually responsible for storing data from and retrieving data into the [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject). In a large scale application this interaction between domain objects and storage logic structures is contained within [services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_%28systems_architecture%29) to isolate the application and domain business logic from leaking in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 1):

`MVC` **is typically a presentation layer framework**, which comes at the top in Presentation based applications. In real enterprise applications, you may have several layers below it.

Typically this is done in another layer: You may name it as `Business Layer` or `Service Layer`.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have posted, you would typically have a Domain / Business Layer / Data Layer sitting beneath your MVC app. If you are looking for a few good examples of how to implement such a stack, using Entity Framework, check out the NerdDinner and MVC Music Store examples.

http://www.nerddinner.com/

http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is some complexity and a great deal of confusion around "layers" and architecture patterns. If you're looking for the simplest answer, and you've decided for the sake of simplicity that each part of your code will lie in one and only one of (model, view, or controller), then my answer to you is choose Model for your database access. The reality is that all architecture patterns are imperfect and you're going to have to just see what feels right with experience.

Answer (score 0):

MVC would only be a *part* of a larger architecture.

Infrastructure issues such as persistence would normally be handled by some classes/objects outside the MVC triad.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What would an exemplary architecture that uses the MVC pattern and saves/loads the model (i.e., some sort of simple document, image, etc., processor application) look like? Where would the logic for saving a file go relative to the MVC logic?

Comment: @weberc2 - There is no "exemplary" architecture. Every application has different architectural needs. But having a method that serializes/deserializes your model entities to disk would be one such option.

Comment: so is there no typical relationship between the model serialization logic and the file I/O logic? If there are typical relationships, What sort of entity might handle file I/O and what would its relationship be with the model?

Answer (score 0):

there doe not have to be any disk io in mvc. if there is, it probably belongs in or near the model, if that is what is being persisted.